# how to use sed to delete some string

Tags: linux, sed

In my case

text:

```
21 130.104.72.201 3124 HTTP [C]±ÈÀûÊ± ·¨ÓïÂ³ãëÌìÖ÷½Ì´óÑ§ 03-05 14:34 0.238
22 129.108.202.10 3128 HTTP [C]ÃÀ¹ú µÂ¿ËÈøË¹´óÑ§ 03-05 14:08 1.983
23 130.88.203.27 3128 HTTP [C]Ó¢¹ú Âü³¹Ë¹ÌØ´óÑ§ 03-05 14:08 0.996
24 129.74.152.66 3124 HTTP [C]·¨¹ú Ê¥Ä¸ÂêÀûÑÇ´óÑ§ 03-05 14:08 0.922
```

command:

```
sed 's/HTTP.*://' ip_all02.txt
```

but nothing was deleted.

Comment: mime works well.

Which platform you are working on?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. I voted to migrate to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do? That will remove everything from the first 'HTTP' to the last ':', like this:

```
21 130.104.72.201 3124 34 0.238
22 129.108.202.10 3128 08 1.983
23 130.88.203.27 3128 08 0.996
24 129.74.152.66 3124 08 0.922
```

...and the results will be dumped to stdout. If you want it in a new file, use > (scrap current contents) or >> (keep current contents) to redirect the output.

```
sed 's/HTTP.*://' ip_all02.txt > ip_all02_clean.txt
```

Comment: Good point. I usually think of -i as being dangerous; I'd usually rather output to another file, check it out to make sure it looks alright, and then copy it back over the original file. Of course if you're dealing with multiple files in a deep directory structure that might not be practical.

Comment: Yes I want this result, but in my machine nothing happen.

Comment: bitshine, it works fine for me. Maybe giving more details about exactly what you're doing and what results you're seeing would help.

Answer (score 1):

if you have gawk/awk on your CentOS, this is another viable option

```
awk '{gsub(/HTTP.*:/,"")}1' file
```